# Oracle Derived Column Based on expression result

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Is there any way to create a derived column based on the result of an expression in 10g?

Specifically, I have inherited a table which contains both character data and numeric data within a varchar2 field.  Obviously, that causes no end of headaches when trying to do joins, as I constantly get "invalid number" errors when Oracle reorders my query which utilizes to_number() on the field.  So, what I'd like to do is create a derived column which has a value if the original column's value is numeric and NULL if it is not and use that in the join rather than the field with mixed types.

Note that I'm attempting to do this in a query, not in a procedure/function.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can come in 10g is a function-based index.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_to_number( p_str IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN NUMBER
  DETERMINISTIC
IS
  l_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_num := to_number( p_str );
  RETURN l_num;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;

CREATE INDEX idx_derived_column
    ON table_name( my_to_number( column_name ) );
```

This generally requires that a function be created and referenced in your query but the function-based index pre-computes the result so you're not actually calling the function at run-time.  If you really want to avoid the function, you could create the index on a `CASE` statement as well and then reference that same `CASE` statement in your query but that would seem to complicate the situation, not make it simpler.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle 11g you can define [virtual columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#CIHCFDDJ):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD (new_column GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN id ...));
```

In 10g and before I would suggest using a view:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN ... END id_number FROM mytable;
```

You could even index your expression with a Function based index for performance (as long as you only use SQL standard functions and deterministic custom functions):

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON mytable (CASE WHEN ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use regular expressions:

```
select * from table where varchar_field not like '%[0-9]%';
```

Comment: I would also suggest putting the [regular expressions](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html) into a subquery, then just joining off of those.  be mindful of two things, (1)it would be best to divorce the "one column to rule them all" and split that table into two columns to avoid just these issues (numbers to numbers, text to text afterall); (2) if you have a column like '12 abc 34 def' you  best make sure your regExp takes the Alphas you want and the numerics you want, but I strongly suggest fixing the table and going with #1

Comment: You can't (easily) decide which clauses get executed first in a query. If the join is performed before the filter, this will cause numeric conversion errors.